# Accessing an instance of a variable from another class in Java

Tags: java, class, buffer, instance

Is it possible to access an instance of a variable in one class from another class in Java.

Let's say you have the following in Class A:

```
private BlockingQueue<byte[]> buffer = new LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]>();
```

I want to make changes to the queue in this class and then be able to use to access it from another class.

How would i access the instance of buffer from another class? Is it even possible?

Comment: Can you make changes to ClassA? If so, add getter method in ClassA and call that from another class by instantiating ClassA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a getter:

```
public class Whatever {

    private BlockingQueue<byte[]> buffer = new LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]>();

    public BlockingQueue<byte[]> getBuffer() {
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Then if you have an instance of Whatever:

```
Whatever w = new Whatever();
BlockingQueue<byte[]> buffer = w.getBuffer();
```

Answer (score 3):

Its usually best to encapsulate collections and not expose the collections itself. Instead you should expose the operations you want to perform

```
public class Whatever {

    private final BlockingQueue<byte[]> buffer = new LinkedBlockingQueue<byte[]>();

    public void enque(byte[] bytes) { buffer.add(bytes); }

    public byte[] takeNext() { return buffer.take(); }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, I was doing that to begin with, but I was having problems so I was doing some error checking using the other method. I agree with you completely.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `private` to `public`. Then you can access the variable buffer like this:

```
A myobj = new A();
BlockingQueue<byte[]> bq = myobj.buffer;
```

For more details, consult this article on access control: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

An arguably better way of doing this is using getters. That is, create a `get()` method in class `A` which simply returns `buffer`.

```
public BlockingQueue<byte[]> getBuffer() {
    return buffer
}
```

Then you can access it by calling `getBuffer()`:

```
BlockingQueue<byte[]> bq = myobj.getBuffer();
```